# Java Script Tableau API - Dynamic viz load

Tags: javascript, api, tableau-api

What am I doing wrong here? URLs do not switch every 5 seconds as intended. Am I using setInterval function incorrectly?

I am trying to pull Tableau viz from the server using JS API.

```
        var vizs = Array ();
        var x=0;

        window.onload=function()  //let html load first
        {   

                vizs[0] = 'url1_dummy';
                vizs[1] = 'url2_dummy';             

                var myVar = setInterval(() => changeViz(), 5000);

                var options = 
                {
                    width: '1800px',
                    height: '800px',
                    hideToolbar: true,
                    hideTabs: true
                }

        function changeViz()
            {
                var vizContainer = document.getElementById('viz')
                var viz = new tableau.Viz(vizContainer,vizs[x], options);  

                    if(x < vizs.length - 1){ x++; } else { x = 0;}
                }


        }
```

Comment: Where is the initial setting of x?

Comment: Please consider changing title to reflect the problem better. Also it would be useful to include more of the code, so that anyone can see how it is actually executed.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: I updated the code to show complete .js file

Comment: @edgars I updated the title as well, is it better?

Comment: It is, but it seems that adding Tableu api would improve it more :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau documentation for dynamic loading shows that the rendered viz element must be destroyed before loading another visualisation. It might be a Tableau API peculiarity.  https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_dynamic_load.htm

```
if (viz) { // If a viz object exists, delete it.
     viz.dispose();
}
var vizURL = vizList[vizCount];
viz = new tableau.Viz(vizDiv, vizURL, options);
```

This also means that you should keep track of `viz` by making it a global variable.